# how to get all selected option select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have many select2 in one page so I want to get all selected option as a array

how it's possible?

i've tried this

```
 console.log($("select").val());
```

but it just gives me the first selected option

Comment: All your complete code please  so that we can help you properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work :

```js
var select = $("select");
var valArray = [];

select.each(function(index){
  valArray.push($( this ).val());
});

console.log(valArray);
```